# What is this interactive graph-drawing control?

Tags: excel, user-interface, graph, controls

What UI control is used to draw this interactive graph diagram?

[image]

Facts about it:

- It's from Excel's [Inquire add-in](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-you-can-do-with-Spreadsheet-Inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42?CorrelationId=2084e29e-45ba-4a13-b2a3-1affb7a6a25a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102835926). It draws dependency diagrams
  of cells, worksheets, workbooks in a form of graph diagram.
- You can
  auto-layout graph nodes, drag them to another place, expand child
  nodes, highlight dependent and precedent nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the DLLs installed with the add-in I would guess it is the GoDiagram control from Northwoods Software.

http://www.nwoods.com/products/godiagram/index.html

The DLL is Northwoods.Go.DLL if you want to search for it. You will also find that tool uses third party DLLs from SyncFusion and Infragistics so I'm not sure if it's a pure implementation of GoDiagram.

Comment: Thanks, GoDiagram looks very similar: http://www.nwoods.com/products/godiagram/samples/Tree%20Diagram%20with%20collapsible%20nodes.png

Comment: Yes, and Northwoods have Microsoft on their list of customers on the website.

Comment: If you are happy with this answer then consider marking it as the best answer to the question please?